# How to find which row has the highest value for a specific column in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I don't know how to find which row would give me the highest value for a specific column in a data frame

For example below.

```
mtcars 
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt ... 
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ... 
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ... 
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ...
```

I am focusing on the wt column and trying to see which one has the highest value, which would be the Mazda RX4 Wag of 2.88

Also how do I find specific values using names instead of vectors? 
For example Mazda RX4 Wag wt. I have tried `df[df$Mazda RX4 Wag,df$wt]` but gives me an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To your fist question.

```
subset(mtcars, wt == max(wt))[, "wt"]
[1] 5.424
```

To your second question

```
mtcars[row.names(mtcars) == "Mazda RX4 Wag", "wt"]
[1] 2.875
```

Answer (score 1):

`drop = FALSE` lets you print the car name i.e. the row name where you have highest or lowest `wt` value

**1. Highest Value of wt column**

To print maximum (Using `max()` function) or highest value of `wt` column.

```
 mtcars[mtcars$wt == max(mtcars$wt), "wt", drop = FALSE]
 #                        wt
 # Lincoln Continental 5.424
```

**OR**

Use `which.max()` as suggested by ycw.

```
  mtcars[which.max(mtcars$wt), "wt", drop = FALSE]
  #                        wt
  # Lincoln Continental 5.424
```

---

**2. Lowest value of wt column**

To print minimum (using `min()` function) or lowest value of `wt` column

```
 mtcars[mtcars$wt == min(mtcars$wt), "wt", drop = FALSE]
 #                 wt
 # Lotus Europa 1.513
```

**OR**

Use `which.min()` as suggested by ycw.

```
 mtcars[which.min(mtcars$wt), "wt", drop = FALSE]
 #                 wt
 # Lotus Europa 1.513
```

Comment: Yes saw that thanks. Even I was observing that. Updated the answer.

Comment: @ycw Never used `which.max`. Thanks will see how that works.

Comment: Works like charm! `which.max` function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
which(name.of.datatable == max(name.of.datatable[, 7]), arr.ind = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row number of the maximum value, use `which.max()`:

```
> which.max(mtcars$wt)
[1] 16
```

To get all the information in that row, use it to subset your data frame:

```
> mtcars[which.max(mtcars$wt),]
                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8  460 215    3 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
```

To select elements of a data.frame by name just insert them as strings. If you want multiple rows or columns you will have to put them into a vector with `c()`.

```
> mtcars['Mazda RX4 Wag','wt']
[1] 2.875
```